# House Building Materials

Tags: terraria

So I want to make some epic bases and whatnot, but I wanted to know what blocks won't register as a house building material? like for example I know meteorite won't be allowed to be built with. what else?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on the [Terraria Wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/House):

> - The side walls (vertical blocks) can be made of blocks, Doors, Platforms or Tall Gates.
> - The floor and ceiling (horizontal blocks) can be made of blocks, Trap Doors or Platforms. The whole floor cannot be made of platforms.

Beyond that, there are no restrictions on specific types of blocks. Houses can be made out of meteorite.